# Pagination in any List<?> Java

Tags: java, spring, arraylist

my objective is create an pagination for any list as i want, by example the list below as 1000 items, and i want to generate an pagination that return propeties as page numbers, item quantity...and others atrributes commons on any pagination. How i can do this? know an library that can  help-me on this? i will use this in an rest api under spring framework.

// any List that contains multiple elements

```
  public List<Integer> anyList() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        //list.add(...) ;
        list.add(1000);
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Are you aware that Spring Data JPA supports pagination? Is this possibly the issue you're trying to solve? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting

Comment: thanks @Json, i know a little about JPA pagination, the thing was to make this pagination from any source.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Jason please refer to the reference he has mentioned for `spring-data-jpa` and follow pagination guide from `spring-data-jpa` and it is the most preferred way of doing. But if you have a data from any other data source and there after you want to do pagination on that list of items then please find my solution using spring `PageListHolder<?>` as below:

Addding test data in controller

```java
 public static final List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            names.add("Name #" + i);
        }
    }
```

Paginating items as below:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/names", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Page<String> names(@RequestParam(name = "page") Integer page,
                         @RequestParam(name = "size") Integer size) {
    PagedListHolder<String> pages = new PagedListHolder<>(names);
    pages.setPage(page);
    pages.setPageSize(size);
    return new PageImpl<>(pages.getPageList());
}
```

[PageListHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/support/PagedListHolder.html) is the actual class extracting `subList` from the main source list, please take a look at its source code as well. Instead of creating new instance of PageListHolder every time you would like to keep it as separate data source class and keep querying.

Comment: If this solves your problem, please consider this as an accepted answer.